# Adding pushState() and popstate to my project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-history

I have a project I'm working on that has a gallery. The way the gallery works is the user is met with a list of images and each image is an "album" that links to more images for the given gallery. I currently have that working, however when the user clicks the back button after going to the selected gallery, they are not taken back to the list of albums. For example, if you are the homepage, click on the albums page, and open a gallery. Upon clicking the back button you are taken back to the homepage.

So I figure to fix this, I can use the history api and use pushState and popstate. My problem is that I haven't been able to get it to work and I'm not sure where to place the functions in my given script.

If you'd like I have a live version of the site I'm working on here: [Live Demo](http://tbaroody-dev.com/gallery/albums.html)

Here is my current script:

```
(function(code) {
  code(window.jQuery, window, document);
}(function($, window, document) {
  $(function() {
    initialize();
  });

  function initialize() {
    $.getJSON('/assets/js/images.json', function(json) {
      $.each(json.albums, function(i, item) {
        var photos = item.photos,
            name   = item.name,
            id     = item.id;

        showAlbums(photos, name, id);
      });  
    });
  }
  function showAlbums(p, n, i) {
    var albums    = $('.albums'),
        gallery   = $('.gallery'),
        album     = $('#templates #album .thumb').clone(true),
        thumbnail = album.find('.thumbnail'),
        image     = album.find('.image'),
        caption   = album.find('.caption h4');

    thumbnail.attr('href', '#').attr('title', n).attr('data-url', i);
    image.attr('src', p[0].href).attr('alt', n);
    caption.html(n);

    albums.append(album);

    album.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      albums.hide();
      gallery.empty().show();
      document.title = "Schultz | " + n;
      $.each(p, function(i, item) {
        var photo = item.href;
        showGallery(photo, n);
      });
    });
  }
  function showGallery(p, n) {
    var gallery = $('.gallery'),
        images  = $('#templates #gallery .thumb').clone(),
        link    = images.find('.thumbnail'),
        image   = images.find('.thumbnail img');

    link.attr('href', p).attr('title', n).attr('data-gallery', '');
    image.attr('src', p).attr('alt', n);

    gallery.append(images);
  }
}));
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: No time to go into a full answer here, but what you want to do is refactor your album click handler into a `showAlbum` function, which, instead of depending on local variables in the scope, accepts in index or ID of the album in the JSON data (which you should be maintaining a reference to instead of just using to init, so you can use it later).  On click of an album you then `pushState` a new URL likely `'?id='+id` and then `showAlbum(id)` to load the view. Then in `window.onpopstate` you'd pull the `id` from the query string and `showAlbum(id)`.

Comment: Then of course if there's no `id` in the query string, you'd just hide the `gallery` and show the `albums` (the case where a user clicks "back" in the gallery view).  UI-wise you'll probably want to add an in page "back to albums" button from the individual galleries.  This sort of thing is particularly important once you start messing with the history, as if a user for example opens the browser on a gallery view there'd be no way for them to go "back" to the albums.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try out what you suggested. Once I figure out the pushstate, the next thing I was planning to do is add a back to albums button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you want to do is refactor your album click handler into a function which can be called *outside* of the initialization to build the album view, then call that function both when the album is clicked, and on `popstate` (back/forward).

To make this happen, you should be storing a reference to the JSON data you're pulling to build the galleries (either the data itself or the XHR you used to retrieve it).  This way we can write a "showAlbum" function that instead takes an index or ID, which we can use to access the selected album in the data.

So something like this:

```
// As you're doing your initialization, process the JSON array of albums
// into a hash by ID (this is one of many ways to go about this, a more
// robust solution would be to use the XHR promise to ensure the JSON is
// always there when you need it).
var albumData = {};

function initialize () {
  $.getJSON('/assets/js/images.json', function(json) {
    $.each(json.albums, function(i, item) {
      var photos = item.photos,
          name   = item.name,
          id     = item.id;

      // Same as you have now, but with this line:
      albumData[id] = item;

      showAlbums(photos, name, id);
    });  
  });
}


// Then we create a function to show an album by ID, essentially the same as
// your click handler now, but retrieving the data from the structure we
// built out of the JSON.
function showAlbumById (id) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var album = albumData[id]
    , photos = album.photos
    , name = album.name;
  albums.hide();
  gallery.empty().show();
  document.title = "Schultz | " + n;
  $.each(photos, function(i, item) {
    showGallery(item.href, name);
  });
});
```

Then you'd replace your album click handler to instead push the state and call that function. Here I'm using a query variable to represent the state in the URL, and `theAlbumId` for clarity (in the code it's referenced by `i`).  If you add a "back to albums" button, you'd do a similar handler but push the URL
without the query var.

```
album.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  history.pushState({}, '', '?id='+theAlbumID);
  showAlbumById(theAlbumId);
});
```

That should handle the pushState part of things, but the popstate part of things requires more work.  We need to be able to go both back and forward between both states: showing a single album, or showing the album index.  To do this you need to add a handler for the popstate event.

```
// define `onpopstate` or add a listener for `popstate` on the window
window.onpopstate = function (state) {
  // pseudocode, you'd need to write or find a function to pull query vars
  var albumId = getQueryParameter('id');

  // if an album ID is in the query string, show it
  if (albumId) {
    showAlbumById(albumId);
  } 
  // otherwise show the index (this should probably be another function)
  else {
    albums.show();
    gallery.empty().hide();
    document.title = "Schultz";
  }
};
```

Then, finally, to handle users refreshing the page or visiting an album URL directly, you'd want to also check the query string for an album ID on page load and show the album just like in popstate (popstate has in some browsers run on page load, but it shouldn't)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I just have a couple questions. First is how do you pass the json data to the showAlbumById function using the above? And is that the functions that would be used to display the given album's gallery? Also does the click event go outside the function or inside the showAlbumsById function?

Comment: 1. You don't need to pass the data to the function because it's stored after gotten initially from the JSON.  So you'd just make the variable `albumData` available to the `showAlbumByID` function by declaring it in the same scope or above.  The way the code is written `showAlbumByID` would never be called until after the JSON request came back, so you'd know it was always there.

Comment: 2. Yes `showAlbumByID` would be called to display an individual gallery and you'd call it on album click, on browser back/forward to a gallery view, and at the end of initialization to load the current gallery (if for example you visited "/mypage.html?id=1" directly or refreshed the page).

Comment: 3. You're binding the album click event in the same place, inside `showAlbums` where you're building out the whole album index.  The handler *calls* `showAlbumsByID` though, so no, it doesn't go inside that function.  Should go in the same place.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I understand what I was missing now.